# Lua Minecraft ComputerCraft function issue

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

Okay so here is my function:

```
function button1()
    mon.clear()
    sleep(.25)
    shell.run("movie")
end
```

Says: "attempt to index ? (a nil value)" for the `shell.run("movie")` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem.

You can't call shell.run() from another program using os.loadAPI()

Comment: This seems like a really weird restriction. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's totally correct. The usecase of `os.loadAPI()` is not to load aditional **active** parts for a program. It is used to load librarys which contain shared functions

Answer (score -1):

so you have declared the mon variable and the function() there are two choices

1. switch the this command to shell.run("monitor side movie")
2. rewrite the program and in the function replace mon.setCursorPos(1.1) to term.setCursorPos(1,1) then when you run the program type "monitor side program" ok